# Angular4 security

Tags: angular

Even when we deploy angular app in production mode, all the external calls made to underlying Node service are fully displayed if you open up browser 'inspect'.

Is there a way to stop this? Or encryption is the only way out?

Comment: What you're asking for is something malware developers would be very interested in. But even if it was possible to somehow block the developer console (maybe unpatched security flaws in browsers), all inbound-outbound traffic client-side can still be examined/analyzed/filtered on the firewall level (if nothing else).

Comment: TLS Encryption.

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP or HTTPS, the server communication is always in plain ASCII text.

- In HTTP, your browser, the server and anyone who has access of the network can see what data you are sending (just like the Network debugger in "Inspect")
- In HTTPS, only your browser and the server knows what data you send (you browser will still show the data in "Inspect")

There are some ways around it, but all of them introduces extra overhead of calculation in the server - because the server has to reinterprete the data.

- You can convert the data in BASE64 format and then make the request - user can still copy that data from "Inspect" and manually convert to normal string.
- You can make POST request instead of GET. Unlike GET, data is sent in the request body rather then embedding it in the URL - user can still see the data if they inspect the payload of that request.
- You can use some crypto library to encrypt the data with some asymmetric key (using symmetric key will defeat the whole purpose) and then send it to server - asymmetric encryption is really heavy on the browser and may make the operation considerably slow.

What you can do is - **Redirect to a new page immediately after you send the data. This can still be bypassed if you preserve the data in Network Inspect.**
*Why:* because the data is the Network "Inspect" is reset when a new page is loaded. So, you can send your data in POST request and the request will send back a redirect header immediately. This will reset the Network debugger.

Comment: @"because the data is the Network "Inspect" is reset when a new page is loaded" - there's this `Preserve log` checkbox, though.

Comment: yes, there is always way around this, unless asymmetric encryption is used.

Answer (score 0):

Code running on the user's machine has no expectation of security. This is a fundamental concept in client-server architecture. You MUST implement security in your API, and assume all requests coming in from clients are untrustworthy.